# Node/React app with Auth0 runs fine locally but not on Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, auth0

I have a react app that I created with create-react-app. It runs fine locally and Heroku. I added Auth0. It ran locally fine. But on heroku, it run fine at home page, then I click on "sign in/sign up" button. It give me this `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`....

[image]

And I noticed in address bar.. the url they tried to use is...

`https://undefined/authorize?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsecret-taiga-61180.herokuapp.com&scope=openid%20profile%20e........(rest of text is deleted for brevity)`

It seems Auth0 used `https://undefined` to start the authentication process. I know the `undefined` is an error. Suppose to be something else.

The `sign on` button worked fine locally. But on Heroku, it errorously go to `https://undefined/...`.

Any idea?

I followed the tutorial from Auth0.com for React Login (using auth0-spa-js 1.0.0) exactly. It worked fine locally. I did input Auth0 config setting in Heroku Setting's config var. And everything else.

Still don't know where the 'https://undefined/' comes from.

Any ideas? anyone encountered this before?

My code is at: `https://github.com/zenkbaries/react-heroku` (it's in 'install-auth0' branch).

Let me know if you need more info.

thanks

John